# Amount of users in a voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to get the amount of users in a vc of the person who sent the command. I also want to make the command only used by people in a vc and have it say "you're not in a VC to run this command" or something close to that.

i tried doing this

```
value=f'{interaction.user.voice.channel.members}/{interaction.user.voice.channel.user_limit}'
```

but it sent this:
[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifA7D.png)

i want something like this though:

[expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw80C.png)

Answer (score -1):

Well by seeing the results you can cleary see that `interaction.user.voice.channel.members` return a Member object while you are looking for an integer.

I think you are probably looking for the `member_count` attribute of the Member object.

EDIT :
Check moinierer300 comment below

That would just return how many users there are on the server. I think you are looking for `value=f'{len(interaction.user.voice.channel.members)/{interaction.user.voice.channel.user_limit}'`

Comment: it gives the error 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'member_count'

Comment: My bad it should be `value=f'{interaction.user.voice.channel.members.guild.member_count}/{interaction.user.voice.channel.user_limit}`

Comment: @BDurand That would just return how many users there are on the server. I think you are looking for `value=f'{len(interaction.user.voice.channel.members)/{interaction.user.voice.channel.user_limit}'`